# Oracle DB Replication/Data Transfer

Tags: oracle, replication, mirroring

[image]

I need to replicate an oracle database without updating each other just for backup purposes.

I have a Main DB(MDB) that have jobs to send to be processed data to interface DB(IDB).  IDB will be updated by an external application. I want the backup of IDB without updating changes to replicated IDB.
I can not control Main DB job to send IDB data for another IDB for back up so I need a software solution.
I there any software solution that can do this scenario?

Comment: Does the external update/delete application run at a particular time, or can it's transactions be identified?

Comment: @TenG external application is running 7/24. Its transaction can be identified.

Comment: So essentially you're looking to backup the Main DB in your scenario?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "unchanging" backup.  And clarify, is IDB getting updates from both "main" db as well as from another application? Exactly what are you wanting to backup, and to what purpose .. how do you anticipate the backup being used?

Comment: I think what is meant by 'unchanging ' is minus the changes made by the external app - essentially backing 'MainDB'. Which begs the question, why not just back up MainDB and in cases of restore of IDB clone from a backup of MainDB. Whys is this not being considered?

Comment: @AhmetArslan Your description is hard to understand. There are three DBs, IDB, MDB and BackupDB (BDB) and an application. IDB is modified  by the application and by MDB. You want to replicate parts of IDB to BDB. Is this  description  correct -Which parts do you want to replicate.